# I can't go to the next activity, using intent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I can't start a 'New Activity' when each item is clicked, I'm using a condition such as if-else,

```
if (item.equals("Aerosol")) {
  startActivity(new Intent(Search.this, Aerosol.class));
  startActivity(intent);
```

I use this there is nothing wrong but I can't go to the next class.

Comment: startActivity(intent); ????? where you have initialised  "intent" ????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to start an intent, declare the Intent in the AndroidManifest as this:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.package.EXCLASS" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application
```

where `.MainActivity` is the name of the class, `com.example.package` is your package name, `EXCLASS` is whatever you would like it to be but remember what you named it.

For every new activity you would like to start, you should redeclare a new `<activity> />` in the AndroidManifest, with the same pacakage name, a new word instead of `EXCLASS`, and the `android:name=".MainActivity"` should change to be an exact copy of the class name with a decimal placed in the front. This should be placed after the `<application> />` declaration so it looks like this:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".StartingActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.package.EXCLASS" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

In your class, MainActivity in my example, you would declare `startActivity(new Intent("com.example.package.EXCLASS"));` where `com.example.package` is your package name, and `EXCLASS` is whatever your declared it to be in the AndroidManifest.

The ending result would be:

```
private void select(String item) {
    try {
        if (item.equals("Aerosol")) {
            startActivity(new Intent("com.example.package.CLASSONE"));
        }
        if (item.equals("Aluminium")) {
            startActivity(new Intent("com.example.package.CLASSTWO"));
        }
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is, instantiate new intent, not calling the intent.

You should do something like this:

```
if (item.equals("Aerosol")) {
    intent = new Intent(Search.this, Aerosol.class);
}else if (item.equals("Aluminium")) {
    intent = new Intent(Search.this, Aluminium.class);
}

startActivity(intent);
```